# esp8266 / arduino serial error 3,6

Tags: esp8266

I am trying to get started with a ESP8266 using Arduino and Sparkfun thing, non dev board. I have cut a trace and an fitted uploading jumper. My FTDI device is one marked 'Deek Rodot'.

I can upload and run programs (blink etc), but if I connect to serial monitor, I have tried Arduino and putty, I get:

```
ets Jan  8 2013,rst cause:2, boot mode:(1,6)
```

with the jumper on and

```
ets Jan  8 2013,rst cause:2, boot mode:(3,6)
load 0x4010f000, len 1384, room 16 
tail 8
chksum 0x2d
csum 0x2d
v09f0c112
~ld
È
```

with the jumper off (after switch off / on)

I've been trying to find a solution for a few days and am wondering if anyone else has gotten through the same problem.

This happens with several different bootloaders I have tried.

Comment: "ets Jan 8 2013,rst cause:2, boot mode:(3,6) load 0x4010f000" etc. is normal, it's the boot loader making itself known (google it). So what is the actual problem your are having?

Comment: normal ??? not according to other reports i've read on the web, after showing the error in terminal it will go no further i cannot send it AT commands i've been through it with Sparkfun tech who say they have seen the problem before but never offered me an explanation.

Comment: Well, what I mean is the start looks like a relatively normal ESP boot, and you say that you can upload and run programs, which suggests both serial and the ESP do work. What you pasted is output of the bootloader I think (the bit before your main firmware), admittedly it is rather cryptic, so there might be something wrong in there, but I can't spot any actual error message, tho I'm not sure what v09f0c112 means, everything before it looks like a small program is loaded, blink?

Comment: Can you possibly describe what you did exactly, in the cleanest example you can think of? Did you erase the flash fully, what parts did you upload to the flash, to which addresses, can you show a screenshot or the command you used, and the name/source of the firmware, bootloader, and other parts you used? You mention AT commands, so I assume you're using the SDK's AT firmware. Which baudrate do you set putty or other clients to?

Comment: And am I correct when I understand the actual problem you are seeing is that you do not get any (legible) output on the serial port, when running a firmware that should provide output? (SDK's AT firmware, NodeMcu firmware, etc.) and also are not seeing any reaction to input on the serial port?

Comment: What I would recommend is getting the latest Espressif SDK, flashing the AT firmware from it exactly according to the instructions from Espressif, and then connecting with putty, making sure the baud rate (Speed) is set to 115200, and the correct com-port is selected, and then typing just 'AT', which should give a reply. That should always work, and if it doesn't you may well have faulty hardware

Comment: hi #cranpin, thank you for the interest you are showing
i will try to explaine exactly what i have tried
with ESP flasher & firmware esp8266_nonos_sdk_v1.5.1_16_01_08_0
i flashed 4 files at addresses as the attachment
the 5th file master_device_key.bin i cannot find anywhere
after flashing power off / on open putty & set port & rate 78440
the first message comes up as before
i try to issue (AT return) but nothing shows in terminal
i can upload sketches from Arduino and they run ok
it is only terminal which refuses to communicate and when it 
does it MUST be at 78440 strange huh

Comment: sorry, couldnt attach picture
0x00000  boot_v1.5.bin
0x01000  user1.2048.new.5.bin
0xFE000  blank.bin
0XFC000  esp_init_data_default.bin

following the instructions at
http://www.allaboutcircuits.com/projects/update-the-firmware-in-your-esp8266-wi-fi-module/

Comment: Well, my first thought is that ESP boots at 78440 baud, but then the AT firmware switches to 115200 baud. So I would set putty to 115200 baud. It will start with noise (while the ESP prints its message at 78440 baud), but after that it should switch to 115200, and allow you to communicate with it (just try AT[enter]).

Comment: after doing this i still cannot upload and run unless i use nodemcu to flash with its inbuilt firmware, then i can upload from arduino and run sketches. My apologies i am still learning to use this site

Comment: That's ok :) When you say you cannot upload, what do you mean? The reason for loading the AT firmware is to check that the serial port works, since the AT firmware is simple and known to work. But it won't do anything else then to reply to AT commands. If we know the serial port works, we can try other firmwares :)

Comment: Also one note, Sparkfun isn't very clean about, but it seems the Sparkfun thing has a quite limited flash size, I didn't realize that at first, it's 4MBit, which is 512kb. It looks like you used the correct addresses for that, but I think the binary should be user1.1024.new.2.bin, not user1.2048.new.5.bin.

Comment: Oh drat! Actually 4MBit is too small for the AT firmware from SDK 1.5.1 and onwards.. That complicates things :)

Comment: Ok, if you still want to try AT firmware, use SDK 1.4.0, and use these addresses: eagle.flash.bin: 0x00000  eagle.irom0text.bin: 0x40000 blank.bin:  0x3e000 & 0x7e000 esp_init_data_default.bin: 0x7c000. You can find them also in the readme.txt in the bin\at folder in the SDK, under NON-BOOT MODE for 4Mbit.

Comment: But since you seem to be able to upload(flash) Arduino sketches, it might be better to focus on that. Can you find/make the simplest sketch you can think of that communicates by serial port, and post the code of the sketch in your question? That way we can see if there's any problem in the code. (and possibly make it blink, so you can see if it is really uploaded/running :) )

Comment: Also, do you understand/know that to get serial output once you've uploaded a sketch, you do need to actually send output from your sketch/code? Also if you set a baudrate in your sketch/code, you won't need to guess what  it is :)

Comment: Just to make sure, to use arduino sketches with the Sparkfun thing, use this tutorial: https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/esp8266-thing-hookup-guide/installing-the-esp8266-arduino-addon, (and the other pages there) but I guess you do that, and user Serial.begin(115200); or some  other number,  to set baud rate, Serial.println("Hello world!"); to actually print something from the ESP to your PC over the serial port

Comment: reseting my brain to 0 and starting again, i think the wood is dissapearing into the trees :-) What you say makes sense. If i upload boot as before with 1.5 the espressif bootloader prog says it worked ok, Then i can upload sketches from Ard and they will run ok (blink & server are two i have tried & work) My only (dare i say it) problem is that if i run Putty i get the message showing the error (3,6) then i cannot input AT commands to Putty. According to all the tuts i've read i should be able to AT it and get OK back, this does not happen, am i correct in my thinking. I will get 1.4 and try

Comment: you are also right saying i could ignore the terminal problem and bash on writing sketches but the fact that terminal doesnt work indicates to me that there is something fundamental wrong either with the boards or with my thinking. the hookup you quote is the one i have been using. i have also spoken to SF tech but they came up with nothing other than suggesting i get a refund (not happy about that :-()

Comment: Well, so far it still seems there might be a logic error, not hardware  :) Just to be very clear: 1. The ESP will only respond to AT commands, when the AT firmware is loaded. 2. If you 'upload' a sketch, it overwrites the AT firmware, so you will not get responses to AT commands.

Comment: So in your case, if you want a response to a AT command, you need to flash the AT firmware, from the 1.4.0, because only that version fits in 4MBit. BUT the AT firmware will overwrite any existing sketch you uploaded, and as soon as you upload a new sketch, it will overwrite the AT firmware, and the ESP won't respond to AT commands anymore

Comment: ahhhhhhhhhhrrrggghh you might well have hit the nail on the head. I will download 1.4.0 now and try it, i'll let you know how I get on, thanks

Comment: ok I got the download from https://github.com/espressif/ESP8266_RTOS_SDK. there are only 3 files in the bin dir, blank.bin, boot_v1.5.bin & esp_init_data_default.bin I put them at FE000, 00000 & FC000 respectively, I could find no user1 bin file in the download, did I get a good download or have I missed something

Comment: I went to http://bbs.espressif.com/viewtopic.php?p=3756#p3756 and got the V1.4 sdk with all the files and flashed that, there were two boot files, I used boot_v1.4(b1).bin flashing went ok but after off / on then open putty at 78440 I get same thing, error message  'ets Jan  8 2013,rst cause:2, boot mode:(1,7)', then cannot talk to terminal or should I then upload a sketch to talk to serial

Comment: Don't use 78440, use 115200 baud :)

Comment: And don't upload a sketch, it will overwrite the AT firmware ;)

Comment: I've not uploaded a sketch since flashing as you said before that it would overwrite the code for the serial. I tried 115200 (putty) and just get rubbish out until I use 78440, and that I think is where all this started. I have ordered some cheap esp8266 01's from china, these two have turned into a liability for you as well as me, I feel guilty taking up so much of your time

Comment: Hehe! Don't feel bad, I like ESP's, that's why i'm helping :) It's disappointing that it didn't give a reply though. After flashing the AT firmware you should get similar replies in putty like in: http://www.allaboutcircuits.com/projects/update-the-firmware-in-your-esp8266-wi-fi-module/. And I'm pretty sure the correct baud rate would be 115200 (though mayby 9600, worth a try, but I'm not hopefull for that). Did the 78440 output say boot mode: 3,7 or 3,6? Otherwise your pins aren't set correctly (still stuck in flash mode)  :)

Comment: dude your a GENIUS!!!!!!!!!!!!! I went to https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/issues/1013 where it says 3,6 was waiting for an upload. at this point I took the boot jumper off (cut trace and fitted it according to the hookup guide) then re-booted 115200 came up with gibberish then 'Ready' I input AT and got OK back....... it works, you have ended a week of pure frustration and I now feel confident to move forward, I owe you a gallon of your favourite tipple, thank you for sticking with me, Dave

Comment: as an afterthought, Sparkfun ships these boards in upload mode (a trace keeps it there ) I cut that trace and fitted a jumper. so this means that all things they ship should potentially show the problem I have been seeing, I think I owe them an email

Comment: Mayby, but it could be more benign then that, it's hard to say without looking at the board in detail. Often the 'flash pin' and 'reset pin' are wired to serail port DTS and RTS, to allow software to reset/flash the board without pushing buttons, so mayby that's what it is. But again hard to say without seeing the layout :) Glad you made progress tho :)

Comment: GPIO0 is taken to 3.3V through 1K also to diode Anode K goes through a trace to DTR  (cutting the trace allows jumper to be fitted) I have fitted the jumper, this is the jumper I needed to remove

Comment: Rst is taken to DTR through 1uF so that if the jumper is fitted DTR going low resets while GPIO0 is held low signalling upload boot

Comment: its also worth noting that while resetting the chip communicates at 74880 but immediately after switches to 115200 so whichever arduino is set to you will read gobbledegook at one point or the other

Comment: Hehe, shopping now, and yes,  you will always get some goobleydook :)

Answer (score 1):

I solve this problem by increasing the input power of my breadboard power supply which I use to power my ESP8266-12E with 3.3V. I guess the ESP8266 requires more current to operate properly. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

According to my [GitHub Page](https://github.com/bijanbina/RAIIS/tree/master/Autism/ESP)
You can solve this problem by using timer instead of direct function call. The reason is ESP8266 need to run some commands every 1000 clock so if the function is a callback and it taking too long it needs to break into other function and called by a timer otherwise following error appears.

```
rst cause:2, boot mode:(3,6)
```

I suggest that change the title. This is NodeMCU bug (probably not ESP8266 or arduino) in my case at least.

- **Be aware that this is a workaround and absolutely not a solutiion.**